# Testing a $http post

Tags: angularjs, mocking, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have this save function:

```
  $scope.save = function(){
    $scope.product.$save(function(){...
```

**Update**
The $save function is inherited from my resource:

```
 .factory('SingleProduct', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/products/:pr_id', {'pr_id':'@pr_id'});
    }
  )
  .factory('SingleProductLoader', function(SingleProduct, $q, $stateParams){
    return function(){
      var delay = $q.defer();
      SingleProduct.get({pr_id:$stateParams.pr_id}, function(product){
        delay.resolve(product);
      }, function(){
        delay.reject('Unable to fetch product');
      });
      return delay.promise;
    };
  })
```

**

This is my test:

```
it('should make a post to /api/products/:pr_id', function(){
    scope.save();
    mockBackend.expectPOST('/api/products/5');
    mockBackend.flush();
  });
```

The "product" is mocked in a beforeEach

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  EditCtrl = $controller('EditCtrl', {
    product: {
      pr_id:5,
      pr_title: 'Eagle',
      pr_env_status_one: 1,
      pr_subcategory: 334,
    }...
```

When I run the test i get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at Scope.$scope.save
```

It works when I try it manually. How do I test this? Should I mock the $scope.product.$save.. somehow?

Comment: I think some code is missing here. Where is the $save method on your product? Where is the 'Scope' variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `$httpBackend` and use it like so:

```
$httpBackend.expect('POST', '/api/products/5').respond(200);
scope.save();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Or use `when(method, url)` if you don't care for checking it strictly.

Answer (score 0):

You should also inject the scope object to your controller:

```
EditCtrl = $controller('EditCtrl', {
    product: {
      pr_id:5,
      pr_title: 'Eagle',
      pr_env_status_one: 1,
      pr_subcategory: 334,
      $scope: scope //<-- here you make sure the scope is the one you made using $rootScope.$new();
    }...
```

furthermore

You should set any expectations before the method execution:

```
it('should make a post to /api/products/:pr_id', function(){
    mockBackend.expectPOST('/api/products/5');
    scope.save();
    mockBackend.flush();
    mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    mockBackand.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
```